# After I appendChild() in ie6, do stylesheets apply to that element?

Tags: dom, internet-explorer-6, domdocument

I am creating some elements in javascript like so:

```
var parent = document.createElement('div');
parent.setAttribute('id', 'parent');

var child = document.createElement('div');
child.setAttribute('class', 'child');

parent.appendChild(child);
otherelement.appendChild(parent);
```

I have a stylesheet which has styles for `#parent` and `.child`.  However, it appears the styles are being applied to the parent but not the child.  Does ie6 only support styles on id's and not classes or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stupid mistakes slipping my mind.  Fixed it with the following code:

```
parent.id = 'parent';
child.className = 'child';
```